# The model is infeasible when I fix some variables to their optimal values

Tags: cplex

I am using Ilog Cplex with Visual C++ 2015 to solve my complex MILP problem. I can get an optimal solution. Now I modify the model. First, I add a constraint to keep the objective to its optimal value. Then I fix all binary variables and part of continuous variables to their optimal value using setBounds function. The modified model is infeasible. However, when I fix all binary variables and all continuous variables to their optimal values, the modified model is feasible. Furthermore, when I only fix all binary variables to their optimal values, the modified model is also feasible. Can somebody deal with this problem?

Comment: And if instead of « add a constraint to keep the objective to its optimal value «  you relax that to not too far from optimal value ?

Comment: Have you tried using the conflict refiner? Also, can you show the relevant part of your code? I.e., can you show how you obtain the optimal objective value and how you add the constraint? Then, like Alex said, this may be a numerical issue.

Comment: Thank you guys. It should be a numerical issue. I get a optimal solution by relaxing the added constraint.